# Android Widget doesn't display data

Tags: java, android, listview, widget, adapter

I am creating an Android Application which is supposed to show a list of items (Strings) in a widget, but for some reason I am unable to get it to work.

Code

Widget Ingredients

```
    package com.example.vamshi.baking.Widget;

import android.appwidget.AppWidgetManager;
import android.appwidget.AppWidgetProvider;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.widget.RemoteViews;

import com.example.vamshi.baking.R;
import com.example.vamshi.baking.Widget.Service.WidgetService;

/**
 * Implementation of App Widget functionality.
 */
public class Ingredients extends AppWidgetProvider {

    static void updateAppWidget(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager,
                                int appWidgetId) {

        CharSequence widgetText = context.getString(R.string.appwidget_text);
        // Construct the RemoteViews object
        RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.ingredients);


        // Instruct the widget manager to update the widget
        appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, views);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds) {
        // There may be multiple widgets active, so update all of them
        final int N = appWidgetIds.length;
        for (int i = 0; i<N; ++i) {
            RemoteViews remoteViews = updateWidgetListView(context,
                    appWidgetIds[i]);
            appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetIds[i],
                    remoteViews);
        }

    }

    private RemoteViews updateWidgetListView(Context context, int appWidgetId) {
        RemoteViews remoteViews = new RemoteViews(
                context.getPackageName(),R.layout.ingredients);

        //RemoteViews Service needed to provide adapter for ListView
        Intent svcIntent = new Intent(context, WidgetService.class);
        //passing app widget id to that RemoteViews Service
        svcIntent.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID, appWidgetId);
        //setting a unique Uri to the intent
        //don't know its purpose to me right now
        svcIntent.setData(Uri.parse(
                svcIntent.toUri(Intent.URI_INTENT_SCHEME)));
        //setting adapter to listview of the widget
        remoteViews.setRemoteAdapter(R.id.list_view_widget,
                svcIntent);

        return remoteViews;
    }

    @Override
    public void onEnabled(Context context) {
        // Enter relevant functionality for when the first widget is created
    }

    @Override
    public void onDisabled(Context context) {
        // Enter relevant functionality for when the last widget is disabled
    }
}
```

Widget Service

```
 package com.example.vamshi.baking.Widget.Service;

import android.appwidget.AppWidgetManager;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.widget.RemoteViewsService;

import com.example.vamshi.baking.Widget.WidgetViewAdapter;

/**
 * Created by Vamshi on 7/27/2017.
 */

public class WidgetService extends RemoteViewsService {

    @Override
    public RemoteViewsFactory onGetViewFactory(Intent intent) {
        int appWidgetID = intent.getIntExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID,
                AppWidgetManager.INVALID_APPWIDGET_ID);
        return (new WidgetViewAdapter(this.getApplicationContext(), intent));
    }
}
```

Widget View Adapter

```
    package com.example.vamshi.baking.Widget;

import android.appwidget.AppWidgetManager;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.widget.RemoteViews;
import android.widget.RemoteViewsService;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.example.vamshi.baking.Data.*;
import com.example.vamshi.baking.Data.Ingredients;
import com.example.vamshi.baking.R;
import com.example.vamshi.baking.Retrofit.IRecipe;
import com.example.vamshi.baking.Retrofit.RetrofitBuilder;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import retrofit2.Call;
import retrofit2.Callback;
import retrofit2.Response;

/**
 * Created by Vamshi on 7/27/2017.
 */

public class WidgetViewAdapter implements RemoteViewsService.RemoteViewsFactory {

    Context context;
    ArrayList<Recipe> r;
    ArrayList<com.example.vamshi.baking.Data.Ingredients> i;
    private int appWidgetID;
    ArrayList<String> iList;

    public WidgetViewAdapter(Context c, Intent in){
        populate();
        this.context = c;
        appWidgetID = in.getIntExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID,
                AppWidgetManager.INVALID_APPWIDGET_ID);

    }

    private void populate() {

        IRecipe irecipie = RetrofitBuilder.Retrieve();
        final Call<ArrayList<Recipe>> recipie = irecipie.getRecipe();
        recipie.enqueue(new Callback<ArrayList<Recipe>>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<ArrayList<Recipe>> call, Response<ArrayList<Recipe>> response) {
                r = response.body();
                i = r.get(0).getIngredients();
                for(int j = 0; j<=i.size(); j++){
                    iList.add(i.get(0).getIngredient());
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<ArrayList<Recipe>> call, Throwable t) {
                Toast.makeText(context, "No Internet Connection", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {

        populate();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDataSetChanged() {

        IRecipe irecipie = RetrofitBuilder.Retrieve();
        final Call<ArrayList<Recipe>> recipie = irecipie.getRecipe();
        recipie.enqueue(new Callback<ArrayList<Recipe>>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<ArrayList<Recipe>> call, Response<ArrayList<Recipe>> response) {
                r = response.body();
                i = r.get(0).getIngredients();
                for(int j = 0; j<=i.size(); j++){
                    iList.add(i.get(0).getIngredient());
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<ArrayList<Recipe>> call, Throwable t) {
                Toast.makeText(context, "No Internet Connection", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {

    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return iList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public RemoteViews getViewAt(int position) {
        final RemoteViews remoteView = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.row);
        Ingredients in = i.get(position);
        remoteView.setTextViewText(R.id.text_for_widget, in.getIngredient());
        return remoteView;
    }

    @Override
    public RemoteViews getLoadingView() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int getViewTypeCount() {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasStableIds() {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Manifest

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.vamshi.baking">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

    <service
        android:name=".WidgetService"
        android:permission="android.permission.BIND_REMOTEVIEWS" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".UI.MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".UI.SecondScreenDetails" />
        <activity android:name=".UI.StepsActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".UI.SingleStepItem" />

        <receiver android:name=".Widget.BakingWidget">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE" />
            </intent-filter>

            <meta-data
                android:name="android.appwidget.provider"
                android:resource="@xml/baking_widget_info" />
        </receiver>
        <service
            android:name=".Widget.Service.WidgetService"
            android:permission="android.permission.BIND_REMOTEVIEWS" />

        <activity android:name=".UI.MasterDetailFlow" />

        <receiver android:name=".Widget.Ingredients">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE" />
            </intent-filter>

            <meta-data
                android:name="android.appwidget.provider"
                android:resource="@xml/ingredients_info" />
        </receiver>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Layout Files

Ingredients.xml

```
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="@dimen/widget_margin">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list_view_widget"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

    </ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

row.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_for_widget"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My aim was to display a list of strings in widget
and since widget does not allow recycler views to be displayed
i had to go for a list view
i had quite a lot of trouble in finding out what was the problem
but i got referred to an amazing article that demonstrates perfectly how to do it
i am posting the link here so incase any of you need help can refer to this

https://dharmangsoni.blogspot.in/2014/03/collection-widget-with-event-handling.html

Answer (score 0):

In your Widget View Adapter make getViewTypeCount return 1.

```
@Override
public int getViewTypeCount() {
    return 1;
}
```

This method provides the number of types of Views that provide that factory.
Also better to make a network calls in IntentService and pass body of response
in intent of RemoteViewsService and this service pass that intent in ViewsFactory, after that ViewsFactory can populate list of Ingredients.